# Displaying and Querying Posts with Featured image

Tags: query-posts, post-thumbnails

I have added Featured image support for my posts by adding the following in the `functions.php`

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

I created 3 posts with Featured Image and i want to display them on the homepage as show in the Read Section in this link http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/

I am trying to do the following to get my posts.

```
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'order' => 'asc'
            );

    $home_shows = new WP_Query($args);
     //   var_dump($home_shows);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($home_shows->posts);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am trying to fetch the Featured Image using the following syntax.

```
    $page = get_page(1);
    print_r($page);
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail(array(486,226));
    } 
the_content();
```

Now i am not sure how to call the featured image to the posts i have queried at the top. as the content is already fetched before am calling the featured image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by cleaning up your code;

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'order' => 'asc'
        );

$home_shows = new WP_Query($args);

//setup your loop here
if( $home_shows->have_posts() ):
    while( $home_shows->have_posts() ): $home_shows->the_post();

    //fetch featured image if exists
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail(array(486,226)); 
    }  

    //fetch content 
    the_content();

    //etc...

    endwhile;
endif;
```

What output do you see?